# How do I investigate an issue with loading a bitmap using BitmapFactory in Android? "getEntry failing because entryIndex..."

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to load a bitmap and display it on a canvas.  I've done it previously using this method and it's worked fine.  Unfortunately, something has gone wrong this time and I don't know how I can track down the problem.

My code gets to here:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Loading bitmaps");
this.stageL=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stagel);
Log.d(TAG,"Bitmap loaded");
int stageLHeight = stageL.getHeight();
Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(stageLHeight));
```

But then I get a warning in the logcat in-between `Loading bitmaps` and `Bitmap Loaded`.  After that the app force closes and I never see the value of `stageLHeight.`

Here's the logcat:

```
11-07 15:22:50.182: DEBUG/LabSetup(613): Loading bitmaps
11-07 15:22:50.182: WARN/ResourceType(613): getEntry failing because entryIndex 3 is beyond type entryCount 1
11-07 15:22:50.182: WARN/ResourceType(613): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020003 (t=1 e=3) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
11-07 15:22:50.182: DEBUG/LabSetup(613): Bitmap loaded
11-07 15:22:50.222: WARN/dalvikvm(613): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
11-07 15:22:50.222: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(613): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
11-07 15:22:50.222: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(613): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 15:22:50.222: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(613):     at com.cjs.duallaseralignment.LabSetup.SetCanvasSize(LabSetup.java:53)
11-07 15:22:50.222: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(613):     at com.cjs.duallaseralignment.MainAppPanel.onDraw(MainAppPanel.java:136)
11-07 15:22:50.222: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(613):     at com.cjs.duallaseralignment.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:56)
```

And in case it's useful, the R.java:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
        public static final int mag=0x7f020001;
        public static final int magr=0x7f020002;
        public static final int stagel=0x7f020003;
        public static final int stager=0x7f020004;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
        public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh darn it!

As a last resort I deleted the images from the project and re-added them, and hey-presto!  Weird...

Answer (score 1):

The error is there in your Logcat.

```
11-07 15:22:50.222: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(613): at com.cjs.duallaseralignment.LabSetup.SetCanvasSize(LabSetup.java:53)
```

It would help if you could point out line 53.

Since you don't get the log telling you the size of the image I would guess that

```
int stageLHeight = stageL.getHeight();
```

is Line 53. And my next guess is that the loaded image is null.
This can happen if the images do not exist, or if the images can not be decoded from the ressource file.